# Keep the day for recurring charges

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am implementing logic for recurring payments.
A charge shall occur 1 month after the last payment.

I am having troubles keeping the day accurate.
Let's say the first payment is on January 30th.
Then I could simply calculate the next billing date by using.

```
moment("2019-01-30").add(1,'month').format();
"2019-02-28T00:00:00+01:00"
```

Which would be what I want.
The problem now is that my next billing date would be the 28th of February and adding one month would result in March 28th as the next payment instead of March 30th as it should be from the first payment.

How can I best solve the issue to keep the date?
I think it could work to save the date as integer and calculate the date based from that but I don't think this would be ideal.

Comment: Why not re-calculate the date always from the initial one?

Comment: You refer to use `.add(2,'month')` next time, etc.?

Comment: Exactly like that. If you want to make your table searchable for payments to be processed, add a column like `nextPayment` which contains the date of the next payment, and re-calculate that date (starting from the initial one) after processing the payment

Comment: do you suggest to add a counter to the db for the amount of months to be added after successful charge or would you calculate that based on the number of successful charges?

Comment: Well, that's up to you. Whatever is easier